# Symfony UploadedFile not working

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I am trying to create a temporary file , Fill it with data and then create a UpladedFile for this temp file. 
Here goes my code.

```
$encoded_data = "This is a huge string";
$filename = "tempMaxFile";//$meta_data["uri"];
$handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, "a+");
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename, $encoded_data);
$file = new UploadedFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename,$filename);
var_dump($file->getClientSize());
die;
```

But it prints null where it should be printing the size of the file.
And I can see the file in my folder with the data in it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code for [UploadedFile](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/File/UploadedFile.php) you will see that it does not calculate this size, it expects you to pass it to the constructor